# Closure e métodos mágicos

Tags: php

Fala galera, tudo ok?

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de envio de nota, porém como aprendemos algo novo a cada dia me deparei com a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho uma closure que trata algumas configurações antes de chamar o envio da nota fiscal no meu sistema, porém estudando mais a fundo algumas ferramentas cheguei ao método mágico `__invoke`.

Vou dar um exemplo prático para vocês(utilizarei um código de exemplo nas duas situações):

> Exemplo de array de configuração:

```
$conf['modeloNota'] = "55"; //65 ou 55
$conf['ambiente']   = 1   ; //Homologação ou Produção
```

> closure

```
$ret = function ($idcliente) use ($conf) {
    if(isset($conf['modeloNota']) && $conf['modeloNota'] == "65") {
        //Aqui vai a chamada da função para o envio da nota modelo 65
        $retorno = strtoupper('nfce');
    }else if(isset($conf['modeloNota']) && $conf['modeloNota'] == "55"){
        //Aqui vai a chamada da função para o envio da nota modelo 55
        $retorno = strtoupper('nfe');
    }else{
        $retorno = "Modelo de nota não definido";
    }

    return $retorno;
};
```

Utilizando o método mágico `invoke`, cheguei a algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class EnvioNota {
    public function __invoke($idcliente ,$conf) {

        if(isset($conf['modeloNota']) && $conf['modeloNota'] == "65") {
            $retorno = strtoupper('nfce');
        }else if(isset($conf['modeloNota']) && $conf['modeloNota'] == "55"){
            $retorno = strtoupper('nfe');
        }

        echo $retorno;
    }
}

$envio = new EnvioNota();
$envio(5, $conf);
```

Os dois funcionam da maneira esperada, porém o que está me intrigando é:

- Qual dos dois métodos é melhor considerado quando se trata em boas práticas de programação?
- Sobre funções que demandam mais quantidade de código é recomendável usar algum destes approaches?
- Existe alguma outra maneira de criar as mesmas funções utilizando outros tipos de funções anônimas?

## Edit:

Segue um exemplo real:
Tenho a seguinte função dentro da minha classe MétodosNF:

```
 $retornoLote = function ($empresa) use ($request){
    $chavenfce = $request->get('xml');
    $xmlAssinado = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/notas/'. preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $empresa->cnpj) . '/' . date('mY') . '/assinadas/' . $request->get('xml').'.xml'));

    $config = [
       "atualizacao" => "2018-02-06 06:01:21",
       "tpAmb" => 2, // como 2 você emitirá a nota em ambiente de homologação(teste) e as notas fiscais aqui não tem valor fiscal
       "razaosocial" => $empresa->razaosocial,
       "siglaUF" => $empresa->endereco->uf,
       "cnpj" => MetodosNF::limpaMascaraCnpjCpf($empresa->cnpj),
       // "schemes" => "PL_008i2",
       "schemes" => "PL_009_V4",
       // "versao" => "3.10",
       "versao" => "4.00",
       "tokenIBPT" => "AAAAAAA",
       "CSC" => $empresa->nfcecsc1,
       "CSCid" => $empresa->nfceidtoken1,
    ];

    $configJson = json_encode($config);

    $filename = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $empresa->cnpj) . '.pfx';
    $certificadoDigital = file_get_contents(public_path() .  '/certificados/' . $filename);

    $tools = new \NFePHP\NFe\Tools($configJson, \NFePHP\Common\Certificate::readPfx($certificadoDigital, '1234'));
    $tools->model(65);

    try {
        $idLote = str_pad(100, 15, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // Identificador do lote
        $resp = $tools->sefazEnviaLote([$xmlAssinado], $idLote);

        $st = new \NFePHP\NFe\Common\Standardize();
        $std = $st->toStd($resp);

        if ($std->cStat != 103) {
            //erro registrar e voltar
            return array('status'=>1, 'mensagem'=>"[$std->cStat] $std->xMotivo");
        }
        $recibo = $std->infRec->nRec; // Vamos usar a variável $recibo para consultar o status da nota
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //aqui você trata possiveis exceptions do envio
        return array('status'=>1, 'mensagem'=>$e->getMessage());
    }

    //Salvar o XML no backup
    Storage::put('notas/'. MetodosNF::limpaMascaraCnpjCpf($empresa->cnpj) . '/' . date('mY') . '/retornoLote/' . $request->get('xml') .'.txt', "[$std->cStat] $std->xMotivo");

    try {
        $protocolo = $tools->sefazConsultaRecibo($recibo);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //aqui você trata possíveis exceptions da consulta
        return array('status'=>1, 'mensagem'=>$e->getMessage());
    }

    try {
        $protocol = new \NFePHP\NFe\Factories\Protocol();
        $xmlProtocolado = $protocol->add($xmlAssinado,$protocolo);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //aqui você trata possíveis exceptions ao adicionar protocolo
        return array('status'=>1, 'mensagem'=>$e->getMessage());
    }

    //Salvar o XML no backup
    Storage::put('notas/'. MetodosNF::limpaMascaraCnpjCpf($empresa->cnpj) . '/' . date('mY') . '/' . $chavenfce.'.xml', $xmlProtocolado);

    //Verifica o logo
    //Só funciona se for jpg
    if(file_exists(public_path() .  '/images/empresa' . \Auth::user()->idglobal .'.jpg')){
        $imagem = asset('images/empresa'. \Auth::user()->idglobal .'.jpg');
    }else{
        $imagem = "";
    }

    //Montagem do PDF
    $docxml = $xmlProtocolado;
    $pathLogo = $imagem;
    $danfce = new Danfce($docxml, $pathLogo, 0);
    $id = $danfce->monta();
    $pdf = $danfce->render();

    Storage::put('notas/' . MetodosNF::limpaMascaraCnpjCpf($empresa->cnpj) . '/' . $chavenfce.'.pdf', $pdf);

    return array('status'=>200, 'url'=>$chavenfce);
}
```

Pensei em criar uma nova classe e reprogramar este fragmento de código, jogando isso dentro de uma classe `retornoLote`, estou estudando uma forma de deixar isto mais "simples" e legível.

Comment: O problema da edição que agora ela pode ser diferente do original, eu respondi baseado no que estava perguntando antes. o Wallace também. Embora analisando melhor nem ocorreu, só não faz sentido na pergunta.

Comment: Você está complicando algo que é mais simples, está encapsulando funções, e piorando a leitura, o grande problema de perguntas assim é porque o cenário nunca podemos ver e automaticamente compreender, talvez, fazer o mais simples possivel, é bem melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Qual dos dois métodos é melhor considerado quando se trata em boas práticas de programação?

Depende de quantas vezes você vai usar a função. Eu diria que `Closures` devem ser usadas apenas quando você vai precisar de um callback, porém o mesmo só vai ser usado em um lugar só.

Se eu precisasse de uma função de callback em mais de um lugar, talvez pensaria em usar o método mágico `__invoke`. Mas ainda assim, `__invoke` é desnecessário, uma vez que você pode trabalhar com funções.

É claro quem alguns casos (raros) você pode usar `__invoke`, sem problemas. Mas eu não definiria uma classe com apenas um método `__invoke`. Se a classe fizesse mais coisas até poderia pensar nisso, mas por padrão, se vai usar o callback mais de uma vez, **recomendo usar funções mesmo**.

No seu caso, fica evidente que está usando o callback apenas uma vez.

> Sobre funções que demandam mais quantidade de código é recomendável usar algum destes approaches?

Eu acho que você deve usar funções anônimas apenas quando precisar de um callback instantâneo (que na maioria das vezes será usado apenas uma vez).

Um pequeno exemplo é quando você precisa ordenar um array com uma regra específica, mas não vai precisar de usar esse callback mais de uma vez, apenas naquele momento.

Você poderia fazer algo como:

```
 $frutas = ['maçã', 'banana', 'melão'];

 // Ordena pelo tamanho da string
 usort($frutas, function ($a, $b) {
      return strlen($a) - strlen($b);         
 });
```

> Existe alguma outra maneira de criar as mesmas funções utilizando outros tipos de funções anônimas?

Essa pergunta está confusa. Só existe um meio de criar funções anônimas: através de closures.

Uma classe implementar a função `__invoke` não a torna uma função anônima.

`__invoke` segundo a documentação:

> O método `__invoke()` é chamado quando um script tenta chamar um objeto como uma função.

Ou seja, é apenas um modificador de comportamento.

A classe `Closure` (que é a instância retornada quando você atribuir uma função anônima a uma variável), também implementa o método `__invoke`, mas você não pode confundir as duas coisas

- Função anônima é a função que não tem nome. Ela retorna uma instância da classe chamada `Closure` que, por sua vez, implementa o método mágico `__invoke`.
- Uma classe que implementa `__invoke` pode ser chamada como função (ou seja, você pode colocar `()` na variável, ou usar `call_user_func_array`). Ou seja, é apenas um modificador de comportamento: A classe vai ser comportar como funçaõ quando for chamada como função.

Comment: Senhor Downvoter, venho por meio desse solicitar um feedback amigável a respeito do vosso negativo ministrado em minhas respostas. Grato.

Answer (score 5):

> Qual dos dois métodos é melhor considerado quando se trata em boas práticas de programação?

Eu tenho só essas duas opções ou eu posso ter minhas próprias opções?

[image: Insert/meme do Pânico na Band]

Esquece esse negócio de boas práticas. Isso serve para nada se não souber o que está fazendo, sem entender de fato o que está lidando, porque, como usa em qual cenário. Um dos motivos que as pessoas estão programando tão mal e fazendo aplicações tão ruins é porque elas acham que basta alguém dizer o que é bom ou ruim e não precisa mais nada pra fazer código bom. Se isso fosse verdade os programadores começariam perder emprego, se a coisa é tão mecânica assim não precisa de tanto programador.

Sem contexto tudo é má prática. E não sabemos qual é o seu contexto, não só da aplicação, da necessidade, mas também do tipo de projeto, em que condições ele está sendo desenvolvido e outras coisas que eu nem lembro, nem sei que é importante neste contexto (sim, tem contextos que são condicionais pelo contexto que está). Sem essas informações tanto faz, tudo será ruim.

Considero as duas opções péssima no que dá para ver porque elas são completamente desnecessárias. Está querendo enfiar a novidade que aprendeu. Não é assim que se programa. O problema deve pedir a solução, não a solução determinar como resolverá o problema.

[image: Plug com gambiarras para entrar na tomada em vez de entrar direto]

> Sobre funções que demandam mais quantidade de código é recomendável usar algum destes approaches?

Não sei se entendi bem o que isso quer dizer, mas já respondi que ambos são ruins.

> Existe alguma outra maneira de criar as mesmas funções utilizando outros tipos de funções anônimas?

Certamente existe, mas pra quê? Não precisa disso. O dia que tiver um problema que exija uma *closure* você usa, mas este problema é resolvido com uma função simples demais com um parâmetro muito simples. Então o segundo é até melhor, mas desnecessário ter uma classe só para ter uma função dentro.

Algo assim era suficiente (não escrevi melhor por nem entender oque esta função deveria fazer, e o código nem é bom ainda):

```
function DescricaoTipoNota($modeloNota) {
    return $modeloNota == "65" ? "NFCE" : $modeloNota == "55" ? "NFE" : null;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/SimpleFunction.php).

As pessoas estão criando códigos muito complicados, longos, sem sentido e que prejudicam a manutenção. E está piorando a cada dia.

A edição da pergunta não mostra nada diferente do que foi dito na essência, apenas mostra que o código como um todo é extremamente mais complicado do que devia ser e comete vários erros, ainda que funcione, na maior parte do tempo, mas isto é outro assunto. Parte da culpa é o componente que está usando que é muito ruim (e só estou falando baseado na API que vi na pergunta, nem o conheço em detalhes). Por sinal nem vi onde *closure* se encaixaria no código postado, pode ser erro meu pelo código estar confuso demais. E a edição tornou a pergunta não clara.

Comment: Na verdade isso é um fragmento de código que usei pra ilustrar, a função realmente é bem extensa, vou colocar um dos exemplos na pergunta.

Comment: @AlvaroAlves não entendi a relação entre o uso de closures e a "função ser bem extensa". Se ela está bem extensa, pode não ser o caso de discutir o que usar, mas sim de codificar melhor.